# Where am i wrong in this calculation of $A\log_2a+B\log_2b = (\log_2 ab^B)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

\begin{align}
A\log_2a+B\log_2b & = A(\log_2a+\frac{B}{A}\log_2b) \\
 & = A(\log_2a+\log_2b^{\frac{B}{A}})\\
 & =A(\log_2 ab^{\frac{B}{A}}) \\
 & = (\log_2 ab^{\frac{B}{A}})^A \\ 
 & = (\log_2 ab^B)
\end{align}

I feel there is something strange,because the sum of the left hand side of formula has a relation with A, I mean if A become smaller or bigger, the sum of left hand side will become smaller or bigger too.

However, it seems that the sum of right hand side, $\log_2ab^B$, doesn't have any relation with A. So I think I make a mistake in somewhere, can anyone tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: You have to be careful with exponentiation, because $\log{(x^A)} \neq (\log{x})^A$

Comment: You've made a great observation that the answer *can't* be right, because $A$ appears on the left, but not on the right --- that's a really good observation, and the kind that'll serve you well in checking things like this in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Last two lines are both wrong. $A(\log_2(a b^{\frac B A}))=\log_2 ((a b^{\frac B A})^{A})=\log_2(a^{A}b^{B})$

Answer (score 3):

The error is that $ab^{B/A}$ means that $b$ is raised to the power of $B/A$, but in the last step you seem to interpret it as $(ab)^{B/A},$ which is **not** the same. That is, in general $(ab^{B/A})^A \ne ab^B$

Another error is is the penultimate step where you should have written $\log_2 ((ab^{B/A})^A)$, but that's minor since you seem to interpret it as that.

Comment: do you know how do i get the $log_2ab^{(B/A)}$ ?

Comment: @electroniccomponent Yes, that step looks fine, given you interpret it as $\log_2(a(b^{B/A}))$

Answer (score 2):

You really have:

$\begin{align*}
A \log_2 a + B \log_2 b
  &= \log_2 a^A + \log_2 b^B \\
  &= \log_2 (a^A b^B)
\end{align*}$

Comment: do you know how do i get the $log_2ab{(B/A)}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

$$
A \log a + B \log b = \log \big(a^A\big) + \log \big(b^B\big) = \log \big(a^A \cdot b^B\big)
$$